# firestore rules are not working while reading and writing the documents from my collections

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote the rules for my firestore database that is only authenticated users can read and write the data into documents. The rule is:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to access documents in the "cities" collection
    // only if they are authenticated.
    match /PhoneAuthUsers/{phoneid=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and i published the rule whenever i run the app i got the error line

> "Missing Insufficient Permissions"

My authentication method is Phoneauthentication and i have the auth id in authentication tab. This is my db structure :

```
**- PhoneAuthUsers(Collection)
     - Phonenumber(documents)
     - Accounts(Collection)
     -autoid(Document)**
```

Client side code :

```
db.collection("PhoneAuthUsers")
    .whereEqualTo("PhoneNumber", mobile)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            System.out.println("hello user");
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    AuthID = document.getId();

                    System.out.print("AuthIDPhonenumber" + AuthID);
                    System.out.println("PhoneNumber");
                    String phone = document.getString("PhoneNumber");
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + phone);
                    if (phone.equals(mobile)) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        System.out.println("count" + count);

                    }
                }
```

When trying to execute the query it shows  missing insufficient permissions.
For example :
**PhoneAuthUsers/+911234567890/Accounts/autoid/Field Values**. when getting the documents from the phoneauthusers i am getting the missing insufficient permissions. How to solve the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that's not working the way you expect.  It should be complete enough that anyone could reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the question by adding the client side . When I try to execute this query it shows missing insufficient permissions.

Comment: It looks like your query just isn't accessing the documents using the structure that you've described.  And, how have you assured that a user is actually logged in at the time of the query?

Comment: The PhoneAuthusers also have fileds values like phonenumber and name and email. so i am checking the user entered phonenumber with the number stored in db under phoneauthusers. it is executed when the rules are public but when restricted it shows insufficient . I didn't understand the question what you asked. could you please explain?

Comment: Your rule demands that the user be signed in, in order to access the collection. I don't see anything in your code that assures this to be true.

Comment: Why we not checking the authentication is We allow two types of users that is directly login into our app and they have the authentication id and the another type of users are :  they are logged from another apps in our eco system  and we save the phone number in my db in a document.  first here the query checks that phonenumber is already in document or not . If already in a document then we use twilio sms other wise we use firebase phone  authentication.

Comment: Yeah, your rule is rejecting all the users that are not known by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190476/discussion-between-vijju-and-doug-stevenson).